# export was not found -- but names still work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I'm sure this is obvious, but I'm not seeing why this isn't working at the moment...

I have a file in a Vue project that exports keycodes in a couple different formats, one to be used for constants (`allCodes`) and another to be used for Vue (`keyCodes`):

```js
export default {
  allCodes,
  keyCodes
};
```

When I try to import one of them using deconstruction like this, I get an error:

```
import { allCodes } from '@/helpers/keycodes';
```

```
21:17-25 "export 'allCodes' was not found in '@/helpers/keycodes'

 warning  in ./src/mixins/GlobalKeyPressHandler.js
```

However, importing then referring to the key by name works:

```js
import object from '@/helpers/keycodes';
console.log('allCodes', object.allCodes);
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want named exports it should be

```
export {
  allCodes,
  keyCodes
};
```

Currently you are exporting an object as default.

BTW "I try to import one of them using deconstruction like this" if you mean that you are trying to use destructuring assignment in imports it wont work. Named import statement is not object destructuring though it looks alike in simplest case.

If you want to have default export than you should make assignment below the import statement

```
export default {
  allCodes,
  keyCodes
};

// importing side
import keycodes from '@/helpers/keycodes';
const { allCodes } = keycodes;
```